# Is there a way that I can make an image as a hint?

Tags: discussion, spoilers

Well, the title describes what I want: usually users post words as a hint, but in my case I have an image ... is it possible to spoiler-tag it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you can.

Put the image markup after the spoiler markup, like this:

> [image: fish - this is the alt text]

Image by [Diliff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Diliff).

Source code for that is:

```
>! ![fish - this is the alt text][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbACz.jpg
```

Comment: oh I didnt know that .. thanks

Comment: No problem @Moudiz. :)

Comment: I can't hit the edit button. It's greyed out.

Comment: oh sorry @mmking, I'll edit my post

Comment: Yeah, suggested edits aren't allowed on Meta: you need to have 1k rep in order to edit at all here.